# Почему возникает ошибка Getting unknown property и странное поведение GridView yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть представление в котором создается GriedvView

```
GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    [
        'format' => 'text',
        'attribute' => 'Дата изменения',
        'value' => date('Y', $tdNews->cdate)
    ],
    [
        'format' => 'text',
        'attribute' => 'Дата публикации',
        'value' => date('Y/m/d', $tdNews->cdate)
    ],
    [
        'format' => 'text',
        'attribute' => 'Прежний заголовок',
        'value' => $news->name
    ],
    [
        'format' => 'text',
        'attribute' => 'Новый заголовок',
        'value' => $tdNews->news_name
    ],
    [
        'format' => 'text',
        'attribute' => 'Автор заметки',
        'value' => $tdNews->user_id
    ],
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
],
```

]);

Данные в него попадают через контроллер вот так

```
    public function actionList() {
    $model = new ThisDay;
    $searchModel = new ThisDay;
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams());
    $editNews = Yii::$app->request->post('ThisDay');

    foreach ($editNews["news_name"] as $year => $name) {

        foreach ($name as $newsId => $text) {
            $news = News::findNews($newsId);
            $model->news_name = $text;
            $model->old_name = $news->name;
            $model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
        }
        $model->save();
    }

    return $this->render('list', ['model' => $model, 'editNews' => $editNews, 'year' => $year, 'name' => $name, 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'searchModel' => $searchModel]);
}
```

не обращайте внимания на код сохранения данные, суть не в нем. Суть в том, что при попытке открыть представление с GridViews получаю ошибку представленную на рисунке ниже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из нее следует что GridView делает примерно следующее 'value' => *обращаюсь к полю модели беря за название поля то, что после "=>"*

Вопрос: почему он поступает именно таким образом? Разве он не должен просто подставлять данные из value в качестве информации в GridView и как можно исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в `value` передавать анонимную функцию (по идее так и нужно).

Пример:

```
'value' => function($data) {
   //здесь в $data будет текущий объект из $dataProvider
   return date('Y', $tdNews->cdate);
}
```

P.S. Не совсем понятно, откуда берётся `$tdNews` в Вашем примере, и что внутри него.

Comment: данные в переменной $tdNews берутся из функции поиска по таблице this_day $tdNews = ThisDay::findThisDayNews($newsId); где $newsId - это id новости в таблице)

Comment: а можете подсказать, что значит "здесь в $data будет текущий объект из $dataProvider" как я могу работать с данными в $data? Или это не для этого нужно?

Comment: внутри этой функции сделайте `var_dump($data);` и увидите то что там внутри

Comment: в том то и дело, что сделал, а там.. типа

`object(yii\data\ActiveDataProvider)#204 (11) {
  ["query"]=>
  object(common\components\db\ActiveQuery)#203 (28) {
    ["sql"]=>
    NULL
    ["on"]=>
    NULL
    ["joinWith"]=>
    NULL
    ["select"]=>
    NULL
    ["selectOption"]=>
    NULL`

и т.д)

Comment: Все, разобрался, модель неправильно отрабатывала, из за этого в провайдере была какая то ерунда)